# Failed to upgrade Linux kernel to 4.0.15-194 on ubuntu 18.04 running on Hyper-v

Tags: 18.04, kernel, hyper-v

I have a windows machine running with Hyper-V running Ubuntu 18.04 32Bit.
The Linux kernel version is : 4.15.0.91-generic.
When trying to upgrade to the recent kernel. 4.15.0-194 it ends but fails to restart.
The last message shown is:

```
Started update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes....el crash signature
```

Since this is Hyper-c machine so I use the option "revert" to the last VM checkpoint, but I prefer to get the main stream updates instead of cherry picking patches.

[Screen shot with log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcfdi.png)

Comment: So the titel should be "kernel to 4.0.15...", not from? However - how does it fail to restart? Have you interrupted the boot process to modify the bootline of grub, to change `quiet splash` to `noquiet nosplash` to read the messages? Did you update via `apt` or how did you do it?

Comment: Thanks, change the title as you suggested.

Comment: Initially I did the update using the `apt` but then after fail I used the "Software updater" tool in order to custom which is the update that failed the boot.

Comment: I have changed to bootline option as you suggested, see the screenshot.

Comment: That's a lot of information, which excludes some premature guesses. I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: That problem does not exits anymore in version 4.15.0.208.